# how to optimize this code -Sonar warning

Tags: java, sonarqube

Sonar giving me warning for too complex method.

I have following code snippet but I am not sure how I can modify it more:

```
for(OrtErgAllType ergAllType : oast.getOrt()) {
    if(ergAllType.getLaenderkennzeichen().equalsIgnoreCase(COUNTRY_CODE)) {
        String plzAndOrt = composePLZAndOrt(ergAllType.getPostleitzahl(), ergAllType.getPostortKurz());
        if (!cities.contains(plzAndOrt)) {
            items.add(new SelectItem(plzAndOrt));
            cities.add(plzAndOrt);        
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the complexity over multiple methods by moving the if-condition or if-satement to new methods and calling them instead.

Something like this:

```
public void stuffFromInsideTheIf(Params...) {
    String plzAndOrt = composePLZAndOrt(ergAllType.getPostleitzahl(), ergAllType.getPostortKurz());
    if (!cities.contains(plzAndOrt)) {
        items.add(new SelectItem(plzAndOrt));
        cities.add(plzAndOrt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge two `if` statements

```
for(OrtErgAllType ergAllType : oast.getOrt()) {
    String plzAndOrt = composePLZAndOrt(ergAllType.getPostleitzahl(), ergAllType.getPostortKurz());
    if(ergAllType.getLaenderkennzeichen().equalsIgnoreCase(COUNTRY_CODE) && !cities.contains(plzAndOrt)) {
        items.add(new SelectItem(plzAndOrt));
        cities.add(plzAndOrt);
    }
}
```